# Google places autocomplete shows error in console in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs version 1.13.X.In my app there is a google places autocomplete search box as a directive.When loading the page following error showing in the console, but search box works fine.

```
InvalidValueError: setComponentRestrictions: in property country: not a string; and not an Array
```

My directive code

```
routerApp.directive('googleplace', ['$state', function ($state) {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, model) {
                    var options = {
                        types: [],
                        componentRestrictions: {}
                        };
                    scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function (e) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            model.$setViewValue(element.val());
                            var countrycode = "na";
                            var latitude = 0;
                            var longitude = 0;
                            scope.secondplacebox = scope.chosenPlace;
                            for (var i = 0; i < scope.gPlace.getPlace().address_components.length; i++) {
                                if (scope.gPlace.getPlace().address_components[i].types[0] == 'country') {
                                    countrycode = scope.gPlace.getPlace().address_components[i].short_name;
                                }
                            }
                            latitude = scope.gPlace.getPlace().geometry.location.lat().toFixed(6);
                            longitude = scope.gPlace.getPlace().geometry.location.lng().toFixed(6);
                            //$state.go('home');
                            scope.Fn_setCookieData(latitude, longitude, countrycode);

                        });
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

How to solve this issue ? Please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

I see the `options` is having `componentRestrictions` and it is not restricted to a particular **country**. Having a country restriction like `componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}` can solve the issue. Replace `fr` with your country requirement. If you do not need the restriction to a country just simply avoid using it in the options.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Yeah true.. Google should take care of the way error messages are thrown to the console.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, but I have changed to the version 3 and it has worked.

```
Before http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MyKey]&libraries=places&language=en

After http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MyKey]&libraries=places&language=en&v=3
```